# Python ssl server blocks when uncertified client connects

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, ssl, python-multithreading

Hi I have written an echo ssl Server. I have a problem with uncertified users! When a user is certified everything is ok, and multiple users can communicate with the server. However, when an uncertified user comes, it will block the server on accept request! Is there any way to solve this issue? Is there any way the reject the uncertified  clients???
server is a class containing a server_socket, When server is created it will bind the server_socket to the port and starts listening.  ConnectionThread is a class responsible for handling communication with client.

```
s = Server(port, secure=SSL)
        while True:
            count += 1
            client_socket, addr = s.server_socket.accept()
            if s.secure:
                # when we have set the server to follow SSL protocol
                try:
                    ssl_client = ssl.wrap_socket(
                        client_socket, keyfile=keypath,
                        certfile=certpath, server_side=True,
                        cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, ca_certs=certpath)
                    if ssl_client:
                        print("Connected to client through SSL" + str(count) + str(ssl_client.getpeername()))
                        print("CERTIFICATES: ")
                        print(pprint.pformat(ssl_client.getpeercert()))
                        client = ConnectionThread(ssl_client)
                        client.client_socket.sendall("Thanks for connecting to me\n".encode())
                        client.start()
                    else:
                        print(" connection request is refused! ")
                except ssl.SSLError as e:
                    print("connection to the client failed : " + str(e.args))
                    continue

#error after stopping the server main processes with Cntr+c
CTraceback (most recent call last): File "echo_server.py", line 74, in <module> cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, ca_certs=certpath) File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.3/ssl.py", line 630, in wrap_socket ciphers=ciphers) File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.3/ssl.py", line 346, in init self.do_handshake() File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.3/ssl.py", line 553, in do_handshake self._sslobj.do_handshake() KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: are you sure it blocks on `s.server_socket.accept()`? What traceback do you get if you send SIGINT to the server (Ctrl+C if it is in the background)?

Comment: Hi Sebastian! Thanks for your interest. 

When I close that client process with Ctr+C, the server will start responding the other certified clients, which wanted to connect to the server, and have been blocked:

the error after catching the ssl.SSLError: 

(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:548)')

Comment: I meant what happens if you interrupt  the server -- the process that calls `accept()` (I also meant foreground (for debugging))

Comment: Don't put it in the comment, [edit] your question instead. Use proper formatting

Comment: OK sorry ! I put it in the question!